# Convert CollectionViewSource to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, collectionviewsource

Once I have filtered a `CollectionViewSource`, is there a way to convert the result into an `ObservableCollection`.

At present, I have used:

```
itemCount = _vm.DisplayItems.View.Cast<MyClass>().Count();
```

where `DisplayItems` is a `CollectionViewSource`, to count the number of items that have successfully passed through the filter.

I would like to get an `ObservableCollection` of these items so that I can perform operations on them like `Skip` and `Take` etc.

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do that?  Generally the `CollectionViewSource` is bound to the ObservableCollection

Comment: Hi @MickyDuncan. Yes, I have bound the `CollectionViewSource` to my `ObservableCollection`. The issue is: After I `filter` the `CollectionViewSource`, I need to use the items in this list for further operations. Hence why I am trying to achieve this. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: I still don't understand why do you need to create new collection? when you filter the data it's displayed in whatever the control you're using, and then you can still use commands on them or even `code-behind`(yuck!). Is there really a need for new collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var l = _vm.DisplayItems.View.Cast<MyClass>().ToList();
```

and if you need a OberservableCollection

```
var c = new  OberservableCollection<MyClass>(l);
```